# uploading an image file to aws s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
import tinys3

 conn =tinys3.Connection(aws_key_id,aws_secrert_key)

 f = open('c:/Users/Akhil/Downloads/New/img033.jpg','rb')
 conn.upload('c:/Users/Akhil/Downloads/New/img033.jpg',f,'matt3r')
```

I am trying to upload an image present in local directory shown below to aws s3 matt3r bucket. when I run this I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "conn.py", line 6, in <module>
conn.upload('c:/Users/Akhil/Downloads/New/img033.jpg',f,'matt3r')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tinys3\connection.py", line 171, in    upload
 return self.run(r)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tinys3\connection.py", line 262, in run
return self._handle_request(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tinys3\connection.py", line 356, in _handle_request
return request.run()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tinys3\request_factory.py", line 346, in run
auth=self.auth)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 123, in put
return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 473, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054,   'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

Comment: have you added permissions to your S3 bucket to **allow AWS Authenticated users** ? Is it implied that you use only tinys3 to do the task? you can use **Boto** which is much better

Comment: @AliEntertainment no...how should I add permissions

Comment: follow---->http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html

Comment: @AliEntertainment I have added the user...is that enough?

Comment: that should work...if you are using the same user credentials

Answer (score 0):

You need to add policy for AWS S3 to your IAM user.